# Is there a cloud credit to reconvert(SVF) the converted file by modifying the converted file(BIM 360 Revit)?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm an autodesk-forge user.
I want to know if it happens about additional cloud credit(Every time I update a Revit file).

https://forge.autodesk.com/pricing

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It belongs to 'Data Management API' if you upload/update files to your bucket or to 
SaaS products such as BIM 360. 'Data Management API' does not charge your cloud credit with current pricing. The cloud credit will be only consumed when the specific API is used, e.g.: Model Derivative  API >> Post Job, which  will ask Forge to translate a source file to the derivatives.

hope this explains.

Comment: I forgot to clarify: <derivatives> means SVF dataset in your case.. In addition, when you update a source Revit file in your bucket, it will not charge you with cloud credit(cc), while if you ask Model Derivative API  to translate again (say a new SVF dataset), then cc will be consumed.  In BIM 360, the SVF derivatives was extracted by BIM 360 automatically, you do not even need to translate file explicitly, but there is prerequsite when working with BIM 360 by API. see the link for details: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/getting-started/get-access-to-account/